# How to change the version of Angular on Plunker

Tags: angular, plunker

I have an Angular 5.2.6 Plunker on plnkr.co, and need to change the Angular version to 5.2.5 to test something. I don't see how to change the version of Angular for the plunk. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that by updating the global variable `window.AngularVersionForThisPlunker` that gets created when you load the Angular (latest version) template.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue

goto the index.html and change 'latest' to the version you want.

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      window.AngularVersionForThisPlunker = 'latest'
    </script>`

else give use the plunk and I will look into it